# Can the cells be sorted on the basis of the colors allotted to a column

Tags: excel

Can the cells be sorted on the basis of the colors allotted to a column instead of A-Z or Z-A?

[image]

Comment: I have removed the [excel-vba] tag as you mentioned in a comment that you don't want a VBA solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for but something like this will soft by color. You are looking for `SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor`

```
Columns("C:C").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"),SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("C2:C6")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

EDIT PER OPs COMMENT: If you just want a sort.
[image]

Pick the custom sort option and select sort on Cell color.

[image]

Comment: where should I put this code? I am a layman not a developer of excel.

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do. It is not just a copy paste sort of thing. see edit to post. If you are looking for a straight excel option try not putting excel-vba as a tag.

Comment: Yes, if it got you the solution you can accept as the answer

Comment: Thanks sir. you have made my income tax return filing very smooth and easy. Cheers!